# retrieve second 10 UNIQUE rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, between, rownum

I want to retrieve the second 10 UNIQUE rows in my sql database, for selecting the second 10 rows, I use the next script:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM (
    SELECT col1, col2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RowNum
    FROM MyTable
) AS MyDerivedTable WHERE MyDerivedTable.RowNum BETWEEN 10 AND 19
```

But now I want the UNIQUE rows in that set, when I use `DISTINCT` like in the next example, the `DISTINCT` also goes over `RowNum` which makes every row a DISTINCT row... how can I exclude the `RowNum` from my `DISTINCT`?

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RowNum
    FROM MyTable
) AS MyDerivedTable WHERE MyDerivedTable.RowNum BETWEEN 10 AND 19
```

Comment: Use `group by` instead of `distinct`.

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Microsoft SQL Server, I'm using it with the Azure environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `group by` instead of `distinct`, as they are applied in different moments of query execution. Of course, since `col1` and `col2` are in N:1 relation with `ID` you need to tell SQL which exact `ID` to use when numbering rows. This can probably be `MAX(ID)`. So:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM (
    SELECT col1, col2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MAX(ID)) AS RowNum
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY col1, col2
) AS MyDerivedTable WHERE MyDerivedTable.RowNum BETWEEN 10 AND 19
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to distinguish those 10 rows in result you can do it in outside `Select` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2 FROM (
    SELECT col1, col2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RowNum
    FROM MyTable
) AS MyDerivedTable WHERE MyDerivedTable.RowNum BETWEEN 10 AND 19
```

Also if you use SQL Server 2012 you can use new sweet statement OFFSET FETCH:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2 FROM (
        SELECT col1, col2
        FROM MyTable
        ORDER BY ID
        OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
    ) AS MyDerivedTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2 
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY ID
LIMIT 10, 19
```

Comment: LIMIT is used with MySQL... SQL doesn't support this (as far as I know)